# Display None but Content Still Appears in Inspector

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

I have a WordPress site up atm where i need to hide the header and footer but still load them. I tried using css to set their display to none but they still appear on the site, is there a way to hide them, have i just done something wrong?
the site is: [Link to website](http://blackfox.nickritson.co.uk/) you can see there is a white band at the bottom.
Or maybe its a problem with something else, i am running this jquery script to set the background of the page to the browsers height.

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('body').css('height',window.innerHeight);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you write a script to remove the header and footer on load. ?

Comment: From looking at your website, the `display: none !important` on the header and footer are working. Are you trying to hide the admin bar at the top? Cause that's a `div` with `id="wpadminbar"`.

But it also might be good to note that your html element has `margin-top: 32px !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Road to the solution:

1. Make sure the CSS rules you have created for this purpose are applicable to the elements you are talking about
2. Make sure that those CSS rules are the most specific CSS rules, [beating any other CSS](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) rule which is in conflict with your `display: none;`
3. Make sure you do not have display in the inline CSS
4. Make sure there is no script adding display value to the given tags
5. Make sure that your CSS is not cached
6. Profit